# What is the number of ways of dividing $2n$ distinct balls into $n$ identical bins, such that each bin contains two balls?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of ways of dividing $2n$ distinct balls into $n$ identical bins, such that each bin contains two balls?

My working was as follows:

First select $n$ balls in $\binom{2n}{n}$ ways, then put one ball into each bin, and arrange it in a total of $n!$ possible ways, then, put the rest of the $n$ balls into the $n$ bins, in one way. This can be done in a total of $\binom{2n}{n} n!$ ways. But there seems to be double counting for each bin, so we need to divide by $2^{n}$ to get the correct answer, i.e, $\binom{2n}{n} \frac{n!}{2^n} $.

My question is how is this double counting happening?
Also, more generally, is there a way to determine how to divide $kn$ distinct balls into $n$ identical bins such that each bin has $k$ balls?

Comment: Did you mean $2n$ balls into $n$ bins?  Are the balls distinguishable?  Are the bins?

Comment: Regardless of the details, I suggest working out a special case with small numbers, like $4$ balls in $2$ bins.  For that one, you can easily write out the full list, subject to whatever constraints you had in mind.  That should show you where you are  double counting.

Comment: Should say:  it seems likely that you are double counting by saying that it matters which order you put the balls in the bins.  Presumably, that order doesn't matter, right?

Comment: @lulu Thanks, corrected the question, and clarified the ambiguities.

Comment: The header is still wrong.

Comment: @lulu It should be alright now.

Comment: Looks good now.  And I stand by my guess as to the source of the double counting.  Try my suggestion for $4$ balls in $2$ bins.  The answer is clearly $3$:  if the balls are $A,B,C,D$ then the entire solution is determined by stating which ball is paired with $A$, and there are $3$ choices for that.  Now do it your way and see if you get $3$ or $6$.  Note:  that method of counting works generally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternative approach:

Index the balls $~B_1, B_2, \cdots, B_{2n}.~$

Use the following algorithm to partner the balls.  Choose the ball of lowest index, whose partner-ball has not yet been decided, and select (at random) one of the remaining (as yet unpartnered) balls to partner with.

So, for the first partnering, which involves ball $~B_1,~$ there are $~(2n-1)~$ choices, because there are $~(2n-1)~$ *other* balls that have not yet been *partnered*.

Regardless of which ball is partnered with $~B_1~$ there will then be $~2(n-1)~$ balls that are still un-partnered.

Whenever there are $~2r~$ balls un-partnered, there will be $~2r-1~$ choices for which *other* ball to partner with the ball of lowest index that has not yet been partnered.

Therefore, the computation must be

$$\prod_{r=1}^n (2r-1).$$

---

> is there a way to determine how to divide $kn$ distinct balls into $n$ identical bins such that each bin has $k$ balls?

Use the exact same approach as in the first problem.

$~r~$ will (again) run from $~1~$ through $~n~$ inclusive.

When there are $~kr~$ balls remaining, the number of choices for the $~(k-1)~$ *other* balls to be partnered with the un-partnered ball of lowest index is $~\displaystyle \binom{kr - 1}{k - 1}.$

Therefore, the computation must be

$$\prod_{r=1}^n \binom{kr - 1}{k - 1}.$$

---

The above analysis begs the question: is it possible that the computation represents either over-counting or under-counting?  Consider any specific distribution of the $~nk~$ balls into $~n~$ distinct groups, of $~k~$ balls each.  Within each group, there will be a unique ball of lowest index.  Further, the $~n~$ groups can be placed in ascending order, by the minimum Ball index pertaining to that group.

Then, there is exactly one way, through the use of the algorithm, that the specific distribution could have occurred.  That is, the groups must have been formed in the ascending order by minimum Ball index, and each specific group must have been formed by choosing $~k-1~$ other balls to partner with the ball of lowest index for that group.

Answer (score 5):

Since the bins are identical, the question essentially reduces to - in how many ways can $2n$ distinct balls be divided into $n$ pairs?

Let's line up the balls in a row. The first two balls make one pair, the next two another pair, and so on. Consider any one arrangement. There are $n$ pairs and they can be arranged among themselves in $n!$ ways. Also, the two balls in each pair can be arranged in 2 ways (so $2^n$ ways for $n$ pairs). That means for each unique grouping, there are $2^n \cdot n!$ arrangements.

Now, $2n$ distinct balls can be arranged among themselves in a row in $(2n)!$ ways.

So the number of unique groupings is $\dfrac{(2n)!}{n! \cdot 2^n}$.

---

> Also, more generally, is there a way to determine how to divide 
> distinct balls into   identical bins such that each bin has 
> balls?

Generalizing the above solution, the required number would be $\dfrac{(kn)!}{n! \cdot (k!)^n}$.

Comment: Surprised that your answer, which is clearly superior to mine, was not chosen to be the accepted answer.  I only posted to provide a somewhat *off-beat*, somewhat inferior approach.

Comment: A case can be made that your solution is more intuitive, and I am not being modest. Thank you for you appreciation, though.

Answer (score 3):

The question  boils down to the # of ways pairs can be formed.

For pairing $2n$ items, the formula  $\large{\frac{(2n)!}{n!2^n}}$ can be understood by noting that in the $(2n)!$ permutations of the items which we can form, neither the order of the pairs nor the order within the pairs matter, thus the division by $n!2^n$

An easy alternative formula is to think of pairs being formed *sequentially*, ie $[(2n−1)(2n−3)(2n−5)...1]$

This skipping by two is called a double factorial and so the formula simplifies to just $(2n−1)!!$

For the generalised case of $kn$ balls with $k$ in each of $n$ bins, it is simpler to revert to the original formula type, thus $\dfrac{(kn)!}{n! (k!)^n}$